# How to reduce this series / sumation?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I was solving a probability problem and I ended up with the solution of the form :

$$
P(\text{event})=\frac{n_{1}}{n}+\frac{n_{2}}{n}\frac{n_{1}}{n-1}+\frac{n_{2}}{n}\frac{n_{2}-1}{n-1}\frac{n_{1}}{n-2} + \frac{n_{2}}{n}\frac{n_{2}-1}{n-1}\frac{n_{2}-2}{n-2}\frac{n_{1}}{n-3}+\cdots
$$

...... so on (up to first $(n_{2}+1)$ terms),
Given that $(n_{1})$ + $(n_{2})$ < (n) and n1>=1, n2>=1

I have tested my solution and it gives correct answer for all set of data available but I want to know if it is possible to reduce it to a simpler form and if yes How can I simplify it further ?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for help writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Is $p_2$ a nonnegative integer, so that if e.g. $p_2=4$ then your sum stops at the last displayed term in your question? (If so that should be stated in the question, and I'd suggest choosing something like $n$ for $p_2$, so it doesn't seem to be a probability.)

Comment: It could be written $$P(event)=n_1\sum\limits_{k=0}^{}\frac{n_2!(n-k-1)!}{(n_2-k)!n!}$$ if that's help.

Comment: The thing on the right of P(event) has been changed from what it was, not only by changing p's to n's, but now there are falling factorials on the $n_2$. (Previously no falling factorials were in the tops of the fractions.) Are you sure this is now the thing you want to sum?

Comment: @coffeemath, yes, this was the original question. someone edited the numerator by mistake!

Answer (score 1):

For every $k\geqslant0$ and $n\geqslant k+1$, let 
$$
S_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{k!(n-i)!}{n!(k-i)!}=1+\frac{k}n+\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}+\cdots+\frac{k!}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}.
$$
The probability $p$ to be evaluated is
$$
p=\frac{n_1}n\,S_{n-1,n_2}.
$$
To compute $S_{n,k}$, note that $S_{n,0}=1$ and
$$
S_{n+1,k+1}=1+\frac{k+1}{n+1}\,S_{n,k}.
$$
From there, an induction on $n$ yields
$$
S_{n,k}=\frac{n+1}{n-k+1},
$$
thus
$$
p=\frac{n_1}{n-n_2}.
$$